# how to use table environment for table properly

Tags: css, html

Being a html layman, I am stuck with creating a table properly.
I have created a minimal html and css to show you my problem.[image: end result]

As can be seen here, there is a huge gape between `Heading` and `content` (possibly due to `cellpadding` tag in table; but if I remove them, the Content # coloumns are too close). So, how can adjust the space properly?

My 2nd problem is about positioning of the `td`. I would like to have this three column(Content 1,2 & 3) to be equally spaced to span the content region, with space between them. Not like quenched to left side as it is now.

How can I do that?
The minimal code is:

trial.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Trial</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="trial.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <table cellpadding="05" cellspacing="10" border="0">
    <tr style="vertical-align:top">
      <td style="vertical-align:text-top">
        <h3>Content 1</h3>
        <ol>
          <li>inp 1</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h3>Content 1</h3>
        <ol>
          <li>inp 1</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h3>Content 1</h3>
        <ol>
          <li>inp 1</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and trial.css:

```
body {
    font : 100% "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color : #0066cc;
    background : #184470;
    margin : 0;
      }
#content {
        background : #e4ecef;
        padding : 0.0em 2.5em;
        width : 62%;
        float : right;
        margin-right : 17%;
        margin-left : 30%;
      }
h2{
  font-size : 200%;
  color : #0066cc;
}
h3{
  font-size : 125%;
  color : #0066cc;
}
```

**NB** From net, possibly I want to do a `div`, and not `table`. But I am confused. Is this NOT the proper usage of table? Kindly advice.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  That doesn't look like something that should be in a table at all, and you only have a single row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably better off using divs rather than a table. Updated your HTML slightly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Trial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="trial.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
              <h3>Content 1</h3>
              <ol>
                  <li>inp 1</li>
              </ol>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
              <h3>Content 1</h3>
              <ol>
                  <li>inp 1</li>
              </ol>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
              <h3>Content 1</h3>
              <ol>
                  <li>inp 1</li>
              </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then your CSS:

```
.row { clear:both }
.column { display:inline-block; width:33% }
```

Setting `display:inline-block` will make the divs display next to each other and I'm setting a width to be 1/3 of the total container. There's a good intro into this and other layout info here http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html